# How to get the last real order Number Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I'm trying to get the last order number in magento 2.
I've tried getting it this way.

```
$objectManager = \Magenato\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$checkout_session = $objectManager>get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
$order = $checkout_session->getLastRealOrder();
$orderId= $order->getEntityId();
$number = $order->getIncrementId();
```

but returns `null`.

Please assist , Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last order number ...

```
$objectManager = \Magenato\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$checkout_session = $objectManager>get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
$order = $checkout_session->getLastRealOrder();
$orderNumber = $order->getId();
echo $orderNumber;
```